# Sorting several individual columns

Tags: vba, excel

```
            Paint   Wallpaper   Furniture   Cars    Bicycles    Newspapers  TVs
Argentina   11      32          34          10      35          50          28
Brazil      46      42          32          20      31          14          49
China       76      11          10          11      37          42          40
Mexico      13      7           26          48      26          25          20
Portugal    12      29          39          48      7           27          40
Singapore   8       17          14          3       23          45          25
Thailand    9       31          43          7       40          14          18
Turkey      48      15          48          11      24          29          2
Uruguay     14      15          38          25      10          36          19
```

I want to separate these columns, then sort each one individually, in descending order, with the country list pasted next to each of the separate product columns and then both sorted by the descending values of the product column.

The following code sorts a specific range of named cells, but I would like to change the code so it addresses the "ActiveCell" and then use the offset function, I think this would be what should work?

```
Sub Macro2()

    Macro2 Macro

    Range("A1:B10").Select
    Range("B10").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B10") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:B10")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what your after. Assuming your data is in first sheet following code will produce the following result in sheet2:

[image]

Code:

```
    Option Explicit

Sub Main()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Call CopyData
    Call SortData
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Private Sub CopyData()

    Sheets(1).Select
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim countries As Variant
    countries = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).Value2

    Dim lastColumn As Integer
    lastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    For currentColumn = 2 To lastColumn
        Sheets(1).Select
        Dim header As String
        header = Sheets(1).Cells(1, currentColumn)
        Dim values As Variant
        values = Sheets(1).Range(Cells(2, currentColumn), Cells(lastRow, currentColumn)).Value2
        Sheets(2).Select
        Dim lastColSheet2 As Integer
        lastColSheet2 = GetLastColumn
        Sheets(2).Range(Cells(2, lastColSheet2), Cells(lastRow, lastColSheet2)).Value2 = countries
        Sheets(2).Range(Cells(2, lastColSheet2 + 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColSheet2 + 1)).Value2 = values
        Sheets(2).Cells(1, lastColSheet2 + 1) = header
    Next currentColumn

End Sub

Private Sub SortData()

    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim lastColumn As Integer
    lastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    For currentColumn = 1 To lastColumn Step 2
        Sheets(2).Sort.SortFields.Clear
        Sheets(2).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Cells(1, currentColumn + 1), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With Sheets(2).Sort
            .SetRange Range(Cells(1, currentColumn), Cells(lastRow, currentColumn + 1))
            .header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

    Next currentColumn

End Sub

Private Function GetLastColumn() As Integer
    If Sheets(2).Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column = 1 Then
            GetLastColumn = 1
        Else
            GetLastColumn = Sheets(2).Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        End If
End Function
```